# Can you give me examples of odd single line comments in C++?

Tags: c++, groovy, comments, header

I wrote a method to remove single line comments from a C++ source file:

```
def stripRegularComments(text) {
  def builder = new StringBuilder()
  text.eachLine {
   def singleCommentPos = it.indexOf("//")
   def process = true
   if(singleCommentPos > -1)
   {
    def counter = 0
    it.eachWithIndex 
    { obj,i ->
     if((obj == '\'') || (obj == '"'))
      counter++
     if(i == singleCommentPos)
     {
      process = ((counter % 2) == 1)
      if(!process)
       return
     } 
    }
```

```
if(!process)
{
 def line = it.substring(0,singleCommentPos)
 builder &lt;&lt; line &lt;&lt; "\n"
}
else
{
 builder &lt;&lt; it &lt;&lt; "\n" 
}
```

}
   else
   {
    builder << it << "\n"
   }
  }
  return builder.toString()
 }

And I tested it with:

```
println a.stripRegularComments("""
this is a test inside double quotes "//inside double quotes"
this is a test inside single quotes '//inside single quotes'
two// a comment?//other
single //comment
""")
```

It produces this output:

```
this is a test inside double quotes "//inside double quotes"
this is a test inside single quotes '//inside single quotes'
two
single
```

Are there some cases I'm missing?

Comment: Those are C++ comments.  C uses `/*` and `*/` to delimit commented sections.

Comment: Just a tip; you might want to look into Regular Expressions

Comment: I don't understand.. The only case for // is from // to \n. What else could there be?

Comment: And while you look at regexps, look at Perl. Perl is extremely powerful and easy when it comes to creating text manipulation scripts.

Comment: @Geo: if you are doing this for production use (say as part of a build system), you might want to look into writing a quick parser. Since you seem to be inclined to java, I would recommend taking a look at http://www.antlr.org/.  Also look at all of the responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877470/how-can-i-strip-multiline-c-comments-from-a-file-using-perl for some more ideas.

Comment: I'd just like to know WHY you're stripping comments out of source code. It doesn't seem like that good an idea.  I mean I think we'd all agree that comments in source are a good thing and should be encouraged.

Comment: @D.Shawley: C99 adopted C++-style comments.

Comment: I'm removing comments because I don't want to implement a full-scale parser. I need to do some light parsing on source files in order to generate some reports.

Comment: There are already many C++ parsers available - have a look at the ANTLR project. You need a parser to do reliable comment processing.

Comment: The nice thing about parsing is that you don't need to parse much more than trigraphs, digraphs, quoted strings, and comments to strip them. I agree that it isn't as easy as it could be, but I think that you are already finding out that a general purpose solution ends up with you writing a parser anyway since it is difficult to catch all of the cases with naive string parsing or REs.

Comment: C++ doesn't have single quoted strings, you can remove that test.

Answer (score 11):

The fun ones are formed by [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) and line continuations.  My personal favorite is:

```
/??/
* this is a comment *??/
/
```

Comment: I haven't seen that in a source file yet.

Comment: @aviraldg: I hope no one would ever do such a thing, but it is within the Standard so it is legal.

Comment: @Geo: oops... yes... this is a multiline since it relies on line continuation (backslash).  I've found accidental line continuation using `??/` at the end of a comment before - basically, `// a comment??/` will comment out the following line. Technically a multiline comment, but completely by accident.

Comment: You have a space character before the first `*`, which ruins the whole thing :) That space character should be removed for your comment to work as intended

Comment: @Andrey: D'oh... I really wish MarkDown didn't require the extra level of indenting for code. It's too easy to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

```
// Single line comments can\
actually be multi line.
```

Comment: I like how the syntax highlighter failed on this one.

Comment: @Kawa: that’s a limitation of the flawed approach to syntax highlighting that Stack Overflow is taking. :-( Even for much more conventional code the results are flaky.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can't handle

```
  puts("Test \
    // not a comment");
```

and this is also likely to make problems:

```
  puts("'"); // this is a comment
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't seem to handle escaped quotes, like:

```
"Comment\"//also inside string"
```

versus

```
"Comment"//not inside string"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the `/* comment */` case.

Comment: I know, I'm planning on doing that after I make sure I've covered the cases for //

Answer (score 1):

The handling of `\` character at the end of the line is performed at the earlier translation phase (phase 2) than replacement of comments (phase 3). For this reason, a `//` comment can actually occupy more than one line in the original source file

```
// This \
whole thing \
is actually \
a single comment
```

P.S. Oh... I see this is already posted. OK, I'll keep it alive just for mentioning phases of translation :)

Answer (score -1):

This is always a favourite:

```
// Why doesn't this run?????????????????????/
foo(bar);
```