# Match comments containing a specific word

Tags: regex

I want to match multiline comments that contain a specific word, let's say `findthis`. The first pattern that comes to mind is `\/\*.*?findthis.*?\*\/` (using `DOTALL`). The problem with this pattern however is that a string like this:

```
/* this is a comment */
this is some text
/* this is a findthis comment */
```

will match the whole text. Basically, on a bigger file, the first match would contain everything from the first comment to the first comment containing `findthis`. How can I prevent this?

Comment: you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618419/can-you-give-me-examples-of-odd-single-line-comments-in-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could change the regex to something like `\/\*([^*]|\*+[^/*])*findthis([^*]|\*+[^/*])*\*+\/` *but*...

To get this exactly right, you would have to fully tokenize the source code. Otherwise your regex will be fooled by comment-like content inside strings (among other bizarre corner cases).

(Explanation of crazy regex:  `([^*]|\*+[^/*])` matches a little bit of the inside of a comment, but never matches all or part of `*/`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

`/\/\*.*?findthis.*?\*\//`. The ? in the `.*?` part means ungreedy. In this way the comment can contain * and / chars, but not */ (the end of the comment)

Comment: That's exactly the same pattern that I posted (with two additional slashes at the beginning and end - because you are probably a PHP user). Have you tried this pattern on the example I provided? It will not work.