# Remove the first comment from a collection of Java source files using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, scripting

I'm trying to remove the first C-style comment (only the first) from a collection of Java source files. At first I tried a multi-line sed, but that didn't work properly so after some Googling it seemed Perl was the way to go. I used to like Perl, it was the first language I ever used to make a web program with, but I've run into a wall trying to get this script to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak

$s=join("",<>);
$s=~ s/("(\\\\|\\"|[^"])*")|(\/\*([^*]|\*(?=[^\/]))*\*\/)|(\/\/.*)/$1 /;
print $s;
```

I call it with the filename(s) of the files to be processed, e.g. ./com.pl test.java. According to everything on the Internet, -i (in-place edit) should redirect output from print statements to the file instead of printing to stdout. Now here's the thing: it doesn't. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to replace the file with the print output. I've tried $^I too but that doesn't work either.

I don't know if it's relevant but I'm on Ubuntu 11.04.

P.S. I'm aware of the pitfalls of regexing source code :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877470/how-can-i-strip-multiline-c-comments-from-a-file-using-perl for inspiration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following not work from the command line?

```
$ perl -pi.bak 's|your_regex|here|' *.java
```

---

#### Inside a script

The script equivalent of the above is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi.bak
s|your_regex|here|;
```

The original post was missing the `p` flag, as pointed out by [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) in his comment.

See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more.

Comment: That works - it's when I try to do in-place inside a Perl script that it stops working. :(

Comment: That's right, you need to have `-n` or `-p`  in order for `-i` to know what to do.  You'll probably want to add `-0777` to make it slurp the whole file.

Comment: Thanks! The solution above works (I added the -0777 too). I have massive respect for people who fully grok Perl scripting. :)

Comment: @Dave : I'm not so sure about 'fully'... we learn something new every day ;)